# Android - get amplitude variation from wav file

Tags: android, android-ndk, avaudioplayer, audio

I am developing android application which will record wav file and after that it should waveform from sound data.

I am using AudioRecorder to record sound from Mic. `

```
bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

    recorder.startRecording();

    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            writeAudioDataToFile();
        }
    },"Innovolt AudioRecorder Thread");

    recordingThread.start();
```

This will store in memory as wav file.
Till this point is ok.

Now I have to get amplitude variation from recorded sound file.

Is there any way to get amplitude array from recorded wav file without playing it? 
 `

Comment: A wav file is typically just raw PCM data with a short header at the start of the file. So you can open it as a binary file and read the samples from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently made library for this recording purpose. you just have to do this :-

```
recorder = OmRecorder.wav(
new PullTransport.Default(mic(), new PullTransport.OnAudioChunkPulledListener() {
    @Override public void onAudioChunkPulled(AudioChunk audioChunk) {
      animateVoice((float) (audioChunk.maxAmplitude() / 200.0));
    }
  }), file());
```

You can get the amplitude very easily! 
you can find more info on this :-

https://github.com/kailash09dabhi/OmRecorder